# Is there any *useful* $f$ who satisfies this properties?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Is there a **useful** (see below to understand bit more what is useful) function with the properties:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0 & x< k\\1 & x\geq k\end{cases}\qquad k\in\mathbb{R}$$

But it couldn't be a piecewise function like

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & x< k \\1 & x\geq k\end{cases}$$

because this type of function can't help so much to manipulate formulas, for use in integration, derivative, transformations, hyperbolic and so on. This kind of function is calculated by a comparision, and I need a calculation using calculus, products, sums, etc.

This kind of function could be very useful and interesting to validate two different formulas. For example, if I have a formula $(g_1(x))$ that holds to a problem when $x<k$ and another that holds when $x\geq k$ $(g_2(x))$, I could use this function $(f(x))$ to wrote something like:

$$h(x)=f(x)g_1(x)+(1-f(x))g_2(x)$$

and this give to me a function $h(x)$ that will hold to all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

To functions in integers we can write something like

$$h(x)=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}+1}{2}g_1(x)+\frac{(-1)^n+1}{2}g_2(x)$$

and the $g_1(x)$ will hold to all $x\equiv 1 \mod 2$ and $g_2(x)$ to all $x\equiv 0 \mod 2$.

**Pratice:**

Here are one example to understand a little about this strange $f$ function.

To $k=0$, $f(x)=0$ to $x<0$ and $f(x)=1$ to $x\geq 0$

Se we can define $$h(x)=f(x)x-(1-f(x))x=xf(x)-x+xf(x)=2xf(x)-x=x(2f(x)-1)$$

and this function, $x(2f(x)-1)$ is the modulus of the absolute value of a real number $x$.

Test this to $x=0$, $x=-1$ (or negative) and $x=1$ (or positive) and you will see.

Comment: Your first and second paragraphs each define a function; in fact, exactly the same function. Therefore, what you are asking seems to be, is there a function $f$ which is not the same as the same function $f$.

Comment: Your question makes no sense, because the function is defined by **what it does**, not by how you *express* what it does.

Comment: The answer is: Yes, it is a step function and is indeed very useful in math and electrical engineering.  See for example the Heaveside Step Function.

Comment: Rahul Narain is right: you specify the function in your first paragraph, and then ask for a different function with the same values.  Strictly speaking, that makes no sense.  Maybe what you mean is: "Is there a way to _describe_ this function without defining it piecewise?"  nubis gives an answer to this question, by describing it as the limit of smooth functions

Comment: Engineers might have a bone to pick with you if you claim the Heaviside step function is not useful...

Comment: @RahulNarain, the truth is the latex that I tried to express the piecewise function in the second paragraph didn't work, so I had removed it.

Comment: @ZevChonoles, well, this question really have sense to me. Several times I need something like this. But, is a little hard define this function precisely but I think the answer below will help me and I will take a look.

Comment: @you, you're right, I was searching a way to describe it withou the piecewise. The truth, describe in a useful way.

Comment: @PeterT.off, I'm not familiated with this function so I will take a look first, but I really hope this function will be *useful*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A large number of functions like this exist, for instance:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(nx)$$

But there is really no reason not to use the [Heaviside step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) as it is popularly called, you can write the derivative as a [dirac delta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

More analytic function that suite your problem can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function#Analytic_approximations) as well.

Comment: Strictly, there is exactly *one* such function :)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Would you be interested in reading a ""paper"" in Spanish I want to present to a professor in the UBA? (it is not long at all, and I'm guessing you'll find it interesting).

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez - There are more than one, as you can see in the Wikipedia link. The logistic function is but one.

Comment: What you mean is that there are *many formulas which give that function* but the function is *one*.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez - There are many functions whose limits converge point-wise to the Heavyside step function.

Comment: For example: let $H$ be the Heavyside step function, take $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ to be any function *whatsoever* and consider the sequence $f_n=H+\frac1n g$, $n\geq1$. Then $f_n\to H$ pointwise.

Comment: @PeterT.off, send me an email.

Comment: @Mariano Where to?

Comment: Google will find my homepage, which has my address :)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I have sent it. Let me know!

Comment: I think is this what I'm looking for $H(x+k)$ holds. Thx.